# Laptop screen goes blank

Tags: windows, display, hardware-failure, laptop-repair

I have been trying to debug this laptop screen issue and the screen kinda flickers then it goes blank. The back light goes out as you can still see what is on the screen but it is very dark.

There was also a type of hissing sound during the flicker and right before it went out.

Any idea what issue might be?

Comment: A broken back-light, I guess. Is your goal to repair it yourself?

Comment: Yes. I hope to anyway. But the weird thing is that sometimes like during the boot up it will stay on a good 30 seconds then mess up but if you take the screen up and down it will work again then break

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most definitely caused by your backlight not working.

Since you're saying it works again for a while when you close and open the laptop lid I'd say it's not the actual backlight lamp itself that is broken but much more likely the connector cable from the laptop body to the cover/display.

Try [ifixit.com](http://ifixit.com) for a disassembly manual for your type of notebook and to have a look at the actual components.

Comment: It might also be the inverter if its not the cable

Comment: Inverter? So the cable itself might be broken? I opened the laptop up and messed with the cable and it still will come up and show for awhile then turn off. open and close it repeats. kinda mimics the laptop being closed